# Magento Insert Event Manager Slider Block in CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have Magento version 1.9.0.1. And am purchased a template. I purchased the Event Manager extension from FME. It is working for the most part, but one of the features is a slider block that you can put on any CMS page that lists upcoming events.

Slider Block for CMS Page

```
{{block type="events/spBlock" name="events.block" template="events/spblock.phtml"}}
```

Copy this code and paste in desired CMS Page (s).

I pasted this in the content section of my home page at the bottom of the content section and nothing shows up.

The extension also says:

Slider Block for Templates

> ```
> echo Mage::app()->getLayout() ->createBlock('events/spBlock') ->setTemplate('events/spblock.phtml') ->toHtml();
> ```
>
> Place this code in desired Template(s) in php tags.

I do not know what they mean by this. Where do I put this? Where in the folder structure? Which `Template`? What precisely does it mean by PHP tags?